# Helper format_number_choice in symfony2

Tags: symfony

Is there any  similar **format_number_choice** helper in symfony2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `transchoice` filter in twig.
See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#twig-templates) for more informations.